# Getting Debugger To Break On Next Event

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

In the Visual Basic 6.0 IDE, it was possible to break a running program that is sitting idle (waiting for an event on the UI thread) then hit F8 (single step). After that, any click, mouse-over, or other event that led to code would cause the debugger to break on the next line of code to execute, which would be the first line of code in the event handler. For example, if you showed a data-entry form with an OK button on it, you could break that form when idle, hit F8, then click the OK button. The debugger then would highlight the first line of code in the cmdOK_Click event handler.

Is there a way to do the above in Visual Studio 2017 with a C# Winforms project? I have seen similar posts on SO that instruct to break all (Ctrl-Alt-Break) then hit F11 (step into) then click a button on the form. But that isn't working. When I hit F11, the program goes back into running mode and events are processed without causing the IDE to break and show the first line to execute after the event.

Note that in the VB6 IDE when you break a program then hit F8 *any* event that fires afterwards and leads to an event handler will cause the IDE to break. I am looking for similar behavior for the VS 2017 IDE and a C# Winforms program.

**Note:** Please don't suggest to go into every even handler and set a breakpoint on the first line of code--consider that a complex program might contain thousands of event handlers, so setting breakpoints within each is not a practical (or elegant) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both F10 (Step Over) and F11 (Step Into) provide the desired behavior, but *only* if **Enable Just My Code** option is on:

[image]

Comment: This is rare and very useful information, and shows a depth of understanding related to how the debugger works that is most appreciated.